# Android - Uploading Imageview on server

Tags: android

I have the following code which picks image from gallery and displays it on Imageview ! All I need to do is to upload this image in imageview on my wamp server ! Can anyone suggest me a working code to put this on server?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 

{

     private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
        private Bitmap bitmap;
        private ImageView imageView;

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.result);
        }

        public void pickImage(View View) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
                try {
                    // We need to recyle unused bitmaps
                    if (bitmap != null) {
                        bitmap.recycle();
                    }
                    InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                            data.getData());
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
                    stream.close();
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```

**Xml File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:onClick="pickImage" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/result" android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"></ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error ?

Comment: No Its working fine I just need to upload that image present in imageview to server !